# Is it posssible in hyperledger fabric remove some transactions from blockchain?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Please advise if it is possible to somehow remove  old blocks from hyperledger fabric ?

I understand that it must be immutable, but what if we do not want to store years old data?

Comment: Well @Jodrell i can somehow comprehend the question. Performance-wise storing allll the 'old data' seems kind of silly and suggests to make the system slow. But that's why they introduce sth like StateDB for example. That's what OP needs to learn/read about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "Archive" feature in Fabric at the moment, but there is an "Epic" in the jira system for an Archive feature.  It has been around for quite a while but it now looks like a high priority.

[Here are the details](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-106).

Comment: Ahhh that's cool. Haven't heard of this one. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not remove transaction from the chain itself. Since otherwise you would destroy the whole thing ([merkle tree](https://www.blockchain-council.org/blockchain/what-is-merkel-tree-merkel-root-in-blockchain/) properties).

But only 'recent' data will be stored in the StateDBs. This is data which is labeled as not deleted. Deleted data will be moved out of this DB. So you could actually think of this as a cache where you can 'quickly' access up to date data. (maybe read [docs about StateDB and Ledger](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/ledger.html?highlight=state) etc in Fabric to get more insights on this)